# Determinant of matrix with trigonometric functions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Find the determinant of the following matrix:
>   $$\begin{pmatrix}\cos\left(a_{1}-b_{1}\right) & \cos\left(a_{1}-b_{2}\right) & \cos\left(a_{1}-b_{3}\right)\\
> \cos\left(a_{2}-b_{1}\right) & \cos\left(a_{2}-b_{2}\right) & \cos\left(a_{2}-b_{3}\right)\\
> \cos\left(a_{3}-b_{1}\right) & \cos\left(a_{3}-b_{2}\right) & \cos\left(a_{3}-b_{3}\right)
> \end{pmatrix}$$For $a_1,\dots ,a_3,b_1,\dots, b_3\in\mathbb{R}$

I'm completely stumped honestly. I tried using the cosine addition identity to open the cosine, but I wasn't able to find how it helps me, and even for a $2\times2$ version of the matrix I wasn't really sure what to do. Any help?

Comment: I think you should try to express this determinant as a product of two matrices determinant.

Comment: Without solving!... The answer is $0$... (Just if you want the answer immediately without steps...) >>> {Wolfram Alpha} (http://goo.gl/jMXjod) Sorry

Comment: @NeilRoy I did that myself as well :P Unfortunately it didn't help me too much...

Comment: Wait, I will write an answer if you didn't get the hint yet.

Comment: @Mann I didn't get it honestly :/ Still thinking about it, I do see that there seems to be a pattern of matrix multiplication after expanding to $\cos(a_i)\cos(b_j)+\sin(a_i)\sin(b_j)$ but wasn't able to take it any further than that...

Comment: Never mind i messed up answer typing, and alex fok already presented a nice one. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The matrix is the product
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{pmatrix}\cos a_1& \sin a_1& 0\\ \cos a_2&\sin a_2& 0\\ \cos a_3&\sin a_3 &0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\cos b_1& \cos b_2&\cos b_3\\ \sin b_1&\sin b_2&\sin b_3\\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}
and thus the determinant is 0.

Comment: Just simply augment the matrices with zero rows and columns. See my edited post.

Comment: Well that makes sense, I failed to see it split like that myself ><". Thank you

Comment: Nice proof!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Notice that your determinant is same as  ,
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{vmatrix}\cos a_1& \sin a_1& 0\\ \cos a_2&\sin a_2& 0\\ \cos a_3&\sin a_3 &0\end{vmatrix}\begin{vmatrix}\cos b_1& \sin b_1& 0\\ \cos b_2&\sin b_2& 0\\  \cos b_3& \sin b_3&0\end{vmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}$$

In determinant multiplication , its is similar to matrix multiplication but the multiplication of $R_iC_j's$ is equivalent to $R_iR_j's$ since $det(A)=det(A^T)$.

Answer (score -2):

Find the determinant of the following trigonometric matrix(unit in radian):

sin1 sin2 sin3 sin4 sin5

sin2 sin3 sin4 sin5 sin6

sin3 sin4 sin5 sin6 sin7

sin4 sin5 sin6 sin7 sin8

sin5 sin6 sin7 sin8 sin9

Comment: How does this answer the question?