# Determinant of a 3x3 matrix with trig.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

So I'm not sure if this is a simple question to solve, but I was going through some exam review for my upcoming Linear Algebra exam and I came across this question.

What is the determinant of the following matrix?

$$
        \begin{vmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \sin^2(a) & \sin^2(b) & \sin^2(c) \\
        \cos^2(a) & \cos^2(b) & \cos^2(c) \\
        \end{vmatrix}
$$

We never went over anything like this in lecture, so I am at a loss as to where I should even start.

I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313013/determinant-of-matrix-with-trigonometric-functions) example but its not quite the same as this question.

Comment: Hint: the sum of two rows equals the third one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: What is the sum of the second and third row?

Comment: @Jake $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$.

Comment: @A.G. Haha, yeah I totally forgot about pythagorean identities.