# Determinant of a matrix with trigonometric functions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Prove:
>
> det
>   $\begin{pmatrix}
>   \cos(a-b) & \cos(b-c) & \cos(c-a) \\
>   \cos(a+b) & \cos(b+c) & \cos(c+a) \\
>   \sin(a+b) & \sin(b+c) & \sin(c+a)
> \end{pmatrix}=-2\sin(a-b)\sin(b-c)\sin(c-a) 
> $.

I know that

$det\begin{pmatrix}
  \cos(a-b) & \cos(b-c) & \cos(c-a) \\
  \cos(a+b) & \cos(b+c) & \cos(c+a) \\
  \sin(a+b) & \sin(b+c) & \sin(c+a)
\end{pmatrix}=2\cdot det\begin{pmatrix}
  \sin a\sin b & \sin b\sin c & \sin c\sin a \\
  \cos a\cos b & \cos b\cos c & \cos c\cos a \\
  \sin(a+b) & \sin(b+c) & \sin(c+a)
\end{pmatrix} 
$

Inspired by seeing the answers of [Determinant of matrix with trigonometric functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313013/determinant-of-matrix-with-trigonometric-functions), I try to tackle this problem likewise,but fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$det=\sum_{cyc}(\cos(a-b)\cos(b+c)\sin(a+c)-\cos(a-b)\sin(b+c)\cos(c+a))=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\cos(a-b)\sin(a+c-b-c)=\sum_{cyc}\cos(a-b)\sin(a-b).$$
In another hand,
$$-2\sin(c-a)\sin(b-c)\sin(a-b)=-(\cos(2c-a-b)-\cos(a-b))\sin(a-b)=$$
$$=\cos(a-b)\sin(a-b)-\frac{1}{2}(\sin(2c-2b)+\sin(2a-2c))=\sum_{cyc}\cos(a-b)\sin(a-b)$$
and we are done.